# How to implement a transition in the Tonkeeper when sending a transaction from the webapp and back after confirmation?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ton

How to implement a transition in the Tonkeeper when sending a transaction from the webapp and back after confirmation?

I'm using a tonconnect-sdk and sending transactions as stated in the documentation:

```
connector.sendTransaction({
  validUntil: Math.floor(new Date() / 1000) + 360,
  messages: [
    {
      address: "0:b2a1ecf5545e076cd36ae516ea7ebdf32aea008caa2b84af9866becb208895ad",
      amount: "100000000"
    }
  ]
})
```